# Steel beam size

Tags: structural-engineering, beam, technical-drawing

I'm a customer not an engineer!
I had 2 sets of drawings for a project to put in bi fold doors.
The original drawing had a beam of 230mm and then the engineer sent a revision with a beam 260mm.
The expanse is 4.3 metres on a brick built UK, 2 storey detached house.
I have just realised, I gave the builder the original drawing! So the beam coming on Monday is 230mm not 260mm. Obviously, I'm concerned what would you do?
Thank you so much.
C

Answer (score 1):

Call both the engineer and the builder, strong enough is one thing but meeting specifications ie building regs is another.

If the engineer won’t sign it off then you have a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advice

Comment: If it requires more strength is there anything that can be done likely to pass regs? I read you can put a steel on top of another but the shortfall is only 30mm or am I likely to be replacing the steels?

Comment: I have welded 20mm plate to each side of some 20 steel I beams, and it was more than sufficient to add the strength required by the engineers and they were looking at many tons for the new machine. Talk to your engineer. You **need** to get this sorted

Comment: Thanks, hopefully I can get this resolved in a similar way. Will speak to engineer first thing Monday :-)

Comment: Plates can be added to the bottom and/or the top  The engineer would need to size these plates to ensure that not only the strength requirements are met but also the deflection limits are met.  It may be quicker and cheaper to re-order the proper beam size than to get the approval from the engineer, get the plates, and have the plates welded by a certified engineer.

Comment: @ForwardEd The beams in my case were vertical so adding to top and bottom was not needed.